# DAX way to return summarised data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, powerquery

I hope I'm not missing an easy solution am still getting used to DAX and can't yet find an appropriate logic.

I have a large dataset, >10m rows which I want to test.  An identifier column "DocumentNumber" might occur on multiple rows and I want to find where the sum of "Value" over these rows for a given "DocumentNumber" is non-zero.

- Tried to use `PowerQuery > removed all` but these two `columns > Group By > DocumentNumber > Sum of Value`. However my 32 bit version of Excel appears to run out of memory performing this step `Expression.Error: Evaluation ran out of memory and can't continue.`
- Wrote a DAX `measure > Sum of Values` and dropped into a pivot table with a view to filtering out the zero values but when I try to drag in the `DocumentNumber` to rows there are more than a million rows so the table won't render.

Is there a logic I should follow in DAX that would achieve step 2 before bringing it to the pivot table? Can DAX actually create a new table in the data model which is the aggregated and filtered data rather than using a pivot? I believe this is possible in PowerBI but not sure about Excel evironment.

Comment: Have you tried using [Summarize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/summarize-function-dax)?

Comment: Hi Rory, i wasn't aware of it but just tried it out and must have my syntax wrong.  I created a two column table `DataTable` with columns `Type` and `Quantity`
Tried to follow syntax on msdn as follows:
'=SUMMARIZE('DataTable'
   ,'DataTable'[Type]
   ,"Summarised Quantity", SUM('DataTable'[Quantity])
   )`
but throws an error that it is referring to mulitple columns which cannot be converted to scalar

Comment: That's probably because you've created a table but you're trying to store it as a measure. Did you click create 'Calculated Table'?

Comment: @Rory thanks for that hint, I wasn't at all familiar with how to work with measure-created tables. Have since done some research and found how to create a table in an XL worksheet, edit the DAX to'EVALUATE

Comment: @Rory thanks for that hint, wasn't familiar with how to work with measure-created tables. Since done some research and found how to create a table in an XL worksheet, edit the DAX to
EVALUATE("SUMMARIZE MEASURE") and this has returned a table of summarized valued by document, great! However this could be a long list as above and not necessarily fit a worksheet table if using a full dataset.  I tried to
EVALUATE(FILTER("SUMMARIZE MEASURE","SUMMARIZE MEASURE"[AggregatedColumnName]) 
again got a DAX error that the expression referred to multiple columns.
Any ideas what's up with filter step?